# In a component how to wait for an action result to invoke other action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, jsx

I am using React + Flux for my application. General flow is I will call action method from JSX component and that action method will invoke store which updates state and emits change event and the state will be updated in JSX component.

Now the problem is, I have separated actions and stores into different files based on their work(2 action files and 2 store files).

Can I write this kind of code in JSX component ? (action2.method2() call is waiting for result of actions1.method1() ). If not, how can I improve this ? method1() and method2() are two different actions methods, so we can't call actions2.method2() inside body of actions1.method1() and also method2 needs access to state updated by method1().

```
this.getFlux().actions.actions1.method1()
        .then(() => {
          this.getFlux().actions.actions2.method2(this.state.method1UpdatedState);
         })
        .catch((error) => { console.log("error : ", error)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping actions as simple as possible, and move all business logic to your stores. So, if you need data from `store1` in `store2` just inject `store1` in your `store2` as a dependency and listen to the specific event, generated by `action1` in your `store2`. You definitely, should avoid implementing this logic in your component.

For example, this how `store2.js` should look

```
import store1 from './store1';

store2.dispatchToken = AppDispathcer.register((payload) => {
   var action = payload.action;

   switch(action) {
       case 'ACTION_1':
         AppDispathcer.waitFor([store1.dispatchToken]);
         let data = store1.getDataFromAction1();
         // ... here you can update store2 data
         // ... and call store2.emitChange();
         break;
   }

});
```